# How can I change part of the composition in MEF after composition?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container, mef, composition

I've setup my app to have a discoverable security service (`ISecurityService`) which has a single method `IPrincipal GetPrincipal()`. Implementers are free to then decide how to get the principal (via domain login, DB etc..). So my app then has parts which do things on startup determined on the roles the user is in, for one example I sections of the interface imported like so:

```
[Import]
public ISecurityService SecurityService {
    get; set;
}
[ImportMany]
public IEnumerable<ISectionPanel> ImportedPanels {
    get; set;
}
public ObservableCollection<ISectionPanel> Panels {
    get; set;
}
public void OnImportsSatisfied() {
    Panels.Clear();
    IPrincipal p = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
    foreach (ISectionPanel sp in ImportedPanels.Where(sp => sp.RequiredRole == null || p.IsInRole(sp.RequiredRole))) {
        Panels.Add(p);
    }
}
```

Don't concentrate too much on the implementation, this is going to change to annotations later, however, the important thing here that made me crop a gutser was that composition of parts was occurring PRIOR to the security principal being set. What this means is I now have a cat and mouse situation.

I've now solved this by using `Lazy<T>` on imports which affected the chaining to occur, however if another implementer of a part forgets to use `Lazy<T>` it may trigger a chained load and cause the app to fail.

What have others used to overcome scenarios such as this?

Previously I had unity which I controlled in a more manual way by simply using `RegisterInstance<T>(T t)`, I've trying to now write apps using the "official" MEF as this comes with the framework and I no longer need to worry about unity.

Ideally what I'd like to be able to do is.

1. Create parts manually at startup prior composition
2. Create a composition container manually adding my pre-built parts (like `RegisterInstance<T>(T t)` in unity
3. Find remaining parts using the usual methods of composition shown in the docs.

Comment: I'm confused: you *say* you get the principal from `ISecurityService.GetPrincipal()`, but your example code actually gets it from `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`. Is this the cause of your problem?

Comment: Nope, sorry, I should have explained. The call to my security services GetPrincipal sets the Thread.CurrentPrincipal during app startup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could initialize your application in two phases:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var container = new CompositionContainer(...))
    {
        // phase 1: compose security service and initialize principal
        var securityService = container.GetExportedValue<ISecurityService>();
        securityService.InitializePrincipal();

        // phase 2: compose the rest of the application and start it
        var form = container.GetExportedvalue<MainForm>();
        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahaa, you just gave me a lightbulb momemnt. From all the MEF documentation at codeplex I figured I was required to call `ComposeParts()` to build the dependency graph, but now I think I understand, I can use MEF more like how I previously would have used Unity to build my graph when I call `GetExportedValue`, any dependencies for that dependency would then be resolved right? I'm so very grateful for you pointing this out to me, personally I think the MEF documentation could be greatly improved :)

Comment: @Brett: right. `GetExportedValue` does pretty much the same thing as Unity's `Resolve`. It's a bit unfortunate that the method name and  documentation is so cryptic about this. That's probably a result of MEF's strong focus on extensibility scenarios (where you would call `ComposeParts` on a few key extension points) rather than full-blown dependency injection.

Comment: Cheers mate, now I've got the two sides of my brain fighting with each other as to moving from Unity to MEF and one side is trying to convince the other to go back to Unity ;)

Answer (score 2):

In MEF, what more or less corresponds to `RegisterInstance` would be the [`AddExportedValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd986383%28VS.100%29.aspx) method.  This would work if the host created the security service without using MEF.  Since you still want to discover the security service with MEF, something like Wim suggests is probably a good solution.

Comment: Thanks so much Daniel, yes I think I had seen this prior, the problem I actually faced was that the security service I wrote also had it's own dependency, one namely as `IUserProvider` which is how id knew where to load the user database such as static (test) or db. I was possibly a little naive in thinking that `ComposeParts` NEEDED to be called after container buildup, but now I've realised this is not the case. You have also helped a bunch Daniel, thankyou very much indeed.